# make: replace prerequisite name in implicit rule

Tags: makefile

I have the following implicit rule in a makefile:

```
a1 b1: %: %.o
```

On invocation, this will look for the prerequisites `a1.o` and `b1.o`. Instead, I want to replace these prerequisites with `a.o` and `b.o`. I've played a bit with `subst` and `$(shell)` but no luck. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the limited case:

```
a1 b1: %1: %.o
```

Alternatively:

```
a1 : a.o
b1 : b.o
a1 b1:
    <the recipe>
```

Comment: Maxim, could you explain the `a1 b1: %1: %o` construct a bit more or give a link to read about it? I can sort of guess how it works, but I have not seen a rule with two colons in it before and would like to know the details.

Comment: It's a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). Basically, the pattern only applies to the targets as in `targets : pattern : prerequisites`.